# Solving a certain type of differential equation of a higher order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xx'''=1$$
then the substitution is made: $$x'=p(x)$$ then it says that :$$x''=p \frac{\partial p }{\partial x}$$ why is this , shouldn't it be just $$\partial p \over \partial x$$

What would $$x'''$$ be then ?

Comment: Mathematica can't find any solutions

Comment: Maple "reduces" it to a complicated first-order d.e., an integration, and an implicit function:
$$x \left( t \right) =s \left( -{{\rm e}^{\int \!g \left( s \right) 
\,{\rm d}s+b}} \right) ^{3/2}
$$ where $$t={{\rm e}^{\int \!g \left( s \right) \,{\rm d}s+b}}+a$$ and $$8\,{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}s}}g \left( s \right) =-{\frac { \left( 3\,{s
}^{2}-8 \right)  \left( g \left( s \right)  \right) ^{3}}{s}}+4\,
 \left( g \left( s \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,{\frac {g \left( s
 \right) }{s}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = x(t)$ (I presume), so $x' = \dfrac{dx}{dt}$.  You have to distinguish between derivatives with respect to $x$ and those with respect to $t$.
Differentiating $x'(t) = p(x(t))$ using the Chain Rule gives you
$$ x''(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} p(x(t)) = p'(x(t)) x'(t) = p(x(t)) p'(x(t))$$
Then
$$ x'''(t) = p(x(t)) \dfrac{d}{dt}(p'(x(t))) + p'(x(t)) \dfrac{d}{dt}(p(x(t))) = p(x(t))^2 p''(x(t)) + p(x(t)) p'(x(t))^2$$